# Remove elements in List<T> that are in Tuple<T1,T2>

Tags: linq, collections, c#-4.0

I have a `Tuple<T1, T2>` which contains the same object that are in a List, when adding the objects from the `List<T>` to the tuple I wish to remove them from the `List<T>`.

I am convinced that I can do this easily using Lamba & Linq:

```
//these objects contain some cards
List<Card> cards;
Tuple<Card, Card> ownedcards;

cards.Select(c => ownedcards); //select owned cards from card collection...
```

but how do I remove those selected cards?  There is no Remove function that takes a list of items to remove?  Do I have to use ForEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cards.RemoveAll(c => c == ownedcards.Item1 || c == ownedcards.Item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Tuple<T1, T2>` isn't a collection, it is a tuple, meaning it holds one item of `T1` and one of `T2`. You can't add something to the tuple, you just can change the properties.

Please describe what exactly you want to achieve, as your current idea isn't possible.

Comment: The tuple just exists, I'm not trying to add something to a Tuple, I'm trying to remove from the cards list the cards in the Tuple.